# read PHP global variable from one page, print in another (both in same PHP class)

Tags: php, jquery, post, controller, forms

I was wondering why my code, which can be trimmed down to the following structure, isn't printing what I think should be printed. Basically I have two methods and two corresponding html pages in the same php controller class. I want to retrieve the value of the POST request (html text input form) from mypage.html and print that in secondpage.html to which we are redirected when the user clicks 'submit' button after typing in their input in the text box.

Update: I just read about PHP sessions and my program does start sessions. But should I use sessions even if the user input date is saved in the database?

```
<? php 

$var; // initializing global variable; 

class MyClass { 

   public function mypage () { 
      global $var; 
      $var = $_POST['form_name']; 
   } 

   public function secondpage () { 
      global $var; 
      print_r($var); 
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be to store the value in the session, like

```
<? php 
class MyClass { 

   public function mypage () { 
      $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['form_name']; 
   } 

   public function secondpage () { 
      print_r($_SESSION['var']); 
   } 

}
```

This expects the session to be started by calling `session_start()` somewhere else, but you said the session is started.

But having the data saved in database, why don't you read it back in the secondpage()?

Comment: thanks for the answer. as for your question, here is why i'm not reading it from the database. I think it would be more efficient to fetch data before it goes to the database, by using session. I **think** it is cheaper to use session variables than read the most recent input to the database. I am a novice in database, though, so if you think this is not a valid thought, any feedback would be great. also this data that I'm trying to toss around across pages is not exactly of sensitive nature, but again I don't know if in general it is good practice to do so with any kind of data.

Comment: I see :) I think your basic idea is correct, using session to store data to be available in the app. There are many classes around to help you with session management, just first google result (session php class): https://gist.github.com/eddmann/10262795. Or the php manual on [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 0):

Using a `global` is awkward in a class. It *feels* wrong. Maybe try a `static` variable instead:

```
<?php 
class MyClass
    {
        public  static $var;

        public function mypage()
            {
                self::$var = 'test'; 
            } 

        public function secondpage()
            { 
                print_r(self::$var); 
            } 
    }

    $test   =   new MyClass();
    $test->mypage();

    // This will print test
    $test->secondpage();
    // This will also print test
    echo MyClass::$var; 
?>
```

If you are literally trying to save from one page to a whole new page, you do need a session.